# How to override/clone modules, which are downloaded to the vendor by composer in zf2?

Tags: php, module, zend-framework2, overriding

SO!!!

I added `zfcUser` module (but I want to do this with any other module too) to my project, based on Zend Framework 2.*. How I can override controllers/views/configs of this module, so changes of them wouldn't be deleted with updating dependencies with composer (I tried to do this and didn't found files are chaned, but what if.... Oo).

I know that there are the way existing to do this, but I don't know it. View Helper? Or what?

Help me, please! Thank you.

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

Current folders and files of ZfcUserOverride:

[image: Current folders and files of ZfcUserOverride]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's answer all your question one by one.

But before let's keep in mind that the ModuleManager is creating the "Application configuration" merging all the modules service configurations (default filename is config/module.config.php within each module) of all registered modules ('modules' key in your application.config.php) starting from the first to the last: this means that the last "wins".

To make a practical example, if you have a configuration key called "XYZ" in module "A" to override its values in module "B", the module "B" must be registered after "A".

Assuming that you want to override ZfcUser configs in your Application module the latter must be registered after the former.

```
'modules' => array(
    'ZfcUser',
    'Application',
),
```

1) How to override *only* view scripts?

As already mentioned, you should create a custom module (I suggest you to use zftool to create new project and module scaffolding) that contains your override custom view scripts inside the views/{module name} folder (views/zfc-user for ZfcUser module). 
Give it a simple try creating the module/{module-name}/view/zfc-user/user/login.phtml file with anything inside it, the visit the /user/login url: you should see your overridden view script.

2) How can I override a controller?

Controllers are registered like services, if you see ZfcUser module config you can find

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'zfcuser' => 'ZfcUser\Controller\UserController',
    ),
),
```

The 'zfcuser' key can be used in the route configuration

```
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'zfcuser', // this refers to the controller service
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
```

In ZfcUser module the user controller, routing rules and template_path_stack have the same name, 'zfcuser' and at first glance it can be confusing, just keep in mind that they refer to different services (view, controller and route config).

To force the application to use your custom controller instead of the ZfcUser's UserController you only need to override the controllers service in your custom module like follow ( for this example I used the Application module)

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'zfcuser' => 'Application\Controller\UserController',
    ),
),
```

Your 'Application\Controller\UserController' can extend the original controller in order to keep the original functionality (perhaps you need to edit only a couple of methods).

3) How can I override a config?

If for 'config' you mean a *service* config just do the same work as point 2: take the configuration key and change its value.

ZfcUser is a configurable module, this means that there are values, any kind of values not necessarily services, that can be configured. Take a look of the config/zfcuser.global.php.dist: this file, renamed without the .dist suffix, can be included in your {Application}/config/autoload directory and the framework will automatically load its content (that will configure the module).
For example you can configure which are the identity fields, whether to use or not captcha, route after login and so on...

I will not explain here how to make a configurable module, there are plenty of tutorial on how to do it.

I hope I didn't mistake anything and that I have answered in a comprehensive manner to your questions, if you have problem just reply :)

Cheers

Comment: I have some questions. Firstly, as you said I changed order of including modules: application is last now. For example, I want to override views of `zfc-user` module. As you said, I created this `\zf2-skeleton\module\zfc-user\view\zfc-user\user\` and copy pasted view files from `vendor\zf-commons\zfc-user\view\zfc-user\user`. I changed `index.phtml`, reloaded page and nothing changed. Why it not works? Should I make equal path (like in vendor)? I mean to add `zf-commons`, so path will be `module\zf-commons\zfc-user...etc`?

Comment: Also, I tried to override controller. Firstly, I have to put file `UserController.php` to the `module\Application\src\Application\Controller\` dir, right? After that, I have to create cfg file `module.config.php` in `module\zfc-user\config`, right? And in it, I have to override controller to  `'zfcuser' => 'Application\Controller\UserController'`. Am I right? That not works too. I did that and nothing works (there are no errors too).

Comment: Same for overriding cfg files. I tried to override cfg file, but I don't think it was overrided. Summarizing: Nothing works and no errors shown too. :'(. [Click me](http://i.gyazo.com/a787586870e88cc074c9bde181322420.png): this is the structure of `module\zfc-user` directory. And [this](http://i.gyazo.com/aa0f6e068365cc8a5d5577083c9659af.png) is the structure of `module\Application\` — src part. What I did wrong? Thank you.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav As I said in my answer below, make sure you include your module **after** the module you're trying to override

Comment: @Ruben, I did so. Look this [image](http://i.gyazo.com/94d08d05e843a2133be9cebdfb6fce86.png). I created directory with same name as module in `\vendor\` directory and thats why (don't know why no errors shown) I get no errors. I forget that I need to create module with DIFFERENT name. Now I did this and look error from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377770/how-to-make-zf2-output-errors-with-simple-formatting) post (I created new post, with another question, but copypasted error there caused by THIS problem, also I will edit my question at this post now).

Comment: @Ruben I updated my question here, in this post. Read it please.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav You need to create a Module.php in your ZfcUserOverride module. That's the minimum requirement of a ZF2 module.

Comment: @Ruben with what contents?

Comment: @Ruben aha!!! I created `Module.php` in `\module\ZfcUserOverride` with same contents as in `\module\Application` but with different namespace. Check new error in the question :))

Comment: @Ruben edited question again. I got how to override view, but struggled with controller. + does `\module\ZfcUserOverride\Module.php` file contents correct?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav You should override ZfcUser's routes to reroute the routes to your own module's controller. A different option is to override the controller alias zfcuser, which I think is what you did. What's not working at this point?

Comment: Yeah, I got it. I can access to the main page of the site, but when I am trying to open `/site/user` (zfcUser module link) I am getting error, as I mentioned in my question (bad idea to past here 100+ symbols).

Comment: Also make sure you have Application\Controller\UserController defined in your service manager config, so it knows how to create an instance of that. If it doesn't have any constructor parameters simply make it an invokable. It would make more sense to put your custom UserController class in the ZfcUserOverride module though.

Comment: @Ruben thank you for your help! I will read it now. I updated my question too. Everything is fine now, but I have some questions. Can you clarify them for me, please?

Comment: @Ruben, hm! Found an error (and I think that I will found more errors in future with that module :'( ) with login form widget. I edited my question again. Can you help me please?

Comment: @Ruben updated it again. Found 1 more thing, which is not working properly.

Comment: I had created new questions with same tag. Some questions about errors. Going to create some new :) Follow if you want.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Your file structure is incorrect. In your view folder change zfc-user-override into just zfc-user.

Comment: @Ruben, I edited my answer. I changed it, because I had been getting error I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav You changed it into zfc-user-override, which is incorrect. :)

Comment: @Ruben. Nope. It was `zfc-user`. I had been getting error: `Unable to render template "zfc-user-override/user/index"`. Only after that, I changed dir name to `zfc-user-override`. Why error appears if dir name is `zfc-user` then?

Comment: The only reason why it would be looking for a template called zfc-user-override is if you're calling the index action on your own custom user controller. If you're using ZfcUser's default index action it will look in zfc-user/user instead.

Comment: @Ruben, `is if you're calling the index action on your own custom user controller` how I can call default controller of `zfcUser` if I overrided it? I overrided contoller, so I am calling the index action of overrided controller. It seems to me it should work so. I overrided controller to do this. Nope? What do you mean by this? Getting accessing to the site by the url or some code?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Well I didn't bring my crystal ball, so I'm not sure what your UserController in your override module looks like. :) Did you extend ZfcUser's UserController? It's pretty simple, just create two view folders: zfc-user and zfc-user-override. Have a subfolder user in each and put all your own module's views in zfc-user-override/user and all the standard zfcuser views in zfc-user/user. You can still override the zfcuser templates that way.

Comment: @Ruben, No, I just copypasted it and added `echo 'bob';` to know if it works. I just put it into the `src/ZfcUserOverride/Controller` folder and changed contoller in the `module.config.php` file.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav you probably just want to extend it and only customize where you actually need it. That's what I'd recommend. That way you can still change the view templates without touching the controller and only create your own controller actions where you need to do something custom.

Comment: @Ruben. I think I understand what are you talking about. It is not neccessary to copy paste whole controller and edit some lines. Better to extend `UserController` class of `ZfcUser\Controller`, right? Right. How I can do this? `class MyUserController extends ZfcUser\Controller` doesn't work. Should I point `ZfcUser\Controller` with use?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Yep, that's exactly what I mean. In your overriding UserController just use something like this: class UserController extends \ZfcUser\Controller\UserController

Comment: @Ruben, hm. I tried it and it says this:  `Class 'ZfcUserOverride\Controller\ZfcUser\Controller\UserController' not found in F:\Server\domains\zf2-skeleton\module\ZfcUserOverride\src\ZfcUserOverride\Controller\UserController.php on line 14`. Looks like zf trying to find `ZfcUser\Controller\UserController` in the wrong place.

Comment: @Ruben and `mini-optimise` question :) How to name overrided module more correctly and more beautifull? `moduleNameOverride` looks monstrous :D

Comment: @SharikovVladislav You should use: extends \ZfcUser\Controller\User including the first \ to resolve to the correct scope.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav As for naming the module it depends on what you're planning to use it for. If you're creating your own re-usable user module that you're planning to use in multiple applications then just YourCompanyNameUser or something would work. Otherwise ApplicationNameUser.

Comment: @Ruben I changed as you said, but now I am getting error `Unable to render template "zfc-user-override/user/index"`. Same for any other action.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Did you create the template for the index action? So zfc-user-override/user/index.phtml?

Comment: @Ruben No there are no templates there. All views are in zfc-user, as you said! Okay.I found the comment, where you said that I have run create two folders. I will try it a later.

Comment: @Ruben is it a trick or the feature? It's not nice to start developing with new platform, learning tricks)))

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Just a figure of speech, no worries. :)

Comment: Why it is necessary to add two folders with name of default module and overrided module?can you clarify that?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav The default ZfcUser views will be looked for in the zfc-user subfolder and your own custom views in your module names subfolder. It's also explained in the ZfcUser docs. Btw not cool to accept a different answer after all the time I put into this. :)

Comment: Oh pleeease don't cry too :((( Look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23386919/2898694). He did something too. Lesser but... :) You have 1+k, he have 100, let him :) You are good in it, so it is not problem to gain rep there for you :) Ok, going to review some your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to create your own module to override everything you want to override.
The views is easy, just add a subfolder called zfc-user in your module's view folder with a subfolder user, so you get YourModule/view/zfc-user/user
In this custom views folder you can simply add your own versions of the ZfcUser templates: login.phtml, register.phtml etc.

For this to work make sure your module is loaded after ZfcUser though. So in your config/application.config.php make sure YourModule comes after ZfcUser in the 'modules' array.

To override the controllers just define your own UserController in your own module, either extending ZfcUsers's UserController or defining your own. Then have the routing take care of the rest. So in YourModule's module.config.php create routes pointing to your own UserController.

**Edit**
Add your custom UserController to your ZfcUserOverride module. Then add it to this same module's module.config.php to the service manager config and alias it with zfcuser which is the name ZfcUser uses.

```
'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'zfcuser' => 'ZfcUserOverride\Controller\UserController',
        ),            
),
```

**Edit 2:**
Also don't forget to add this to your module.config.php:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'zfcuser' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

This is required if you're overriding ZfcUser's view scripts.