# How to make zf2 output errors with simple formatting?

Tags: php, error-handling, zend-framework2, stack-trace

I am newbie with zf2 framework. For example, now I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with  message 'Module (ZfcUserOverride) could not be initialized.' in F:\Server\domains\zf2-skeleton\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php:189 Stack trace: 
#0 F:\Server\domains\zf2-skeleton\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php(163): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModuleByName(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) 
#1 F:\Server\domains\zf2-skeleton\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php(90): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModule('ZfcUserOverride') 
#2 [internal function]: Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->onLoadModules(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) 
#3 F:\Server\domains\zf2-skeleton\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) 
#4 F:\Server\domains\zf2-skeleton\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('loadModules', Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent), NULL) 
#5 F:\Server\domains\zf2-skeleton\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php(109): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('loadModules', Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager), Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) 
#6 F:\Server\domains\zf2-skeleton\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(252): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModules() 
#7 F:\Server\domains\zf2-skeleton\public\index.php(17): Zend\Mvc\Application::init(Array) 
#8 {main} thrown in F:\Server\domains\zf2-skeleton\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php on line 189
```

I formatted it manually, so you can read correct error.

It is hard to do it all time I get some error. How I can make zf2 to output such errors correctly?

I need something like this:

[image]

Comment: Which errors? If the question relates specifically to your ZF2 application then you will need to just [modify the standard error template](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/view/error/index.phtml) or just [create a custom error template](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2013/07/21/how-to-override-error-layout-in-zf2-app/). If it is just 'normal' error formatting; I would recommend [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace) (with HTML errors turned on).

Comment: Errors like I mentioned in example. For example, such error appears if I forget to create `Module.php` file in some module. It is 1 big string with any text-indents and line breaks. The question is how to add that indents and breaks?

Comment: @AlexP updated question with an example

Answer (score 0):

The [ZendSkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) comes with a template that reports errors in a readable format.  If you install the ZendSkeletonApplication and build your application off of it, you’ll benefit from this template and other conveniences.  Alternatively, you can use just the [standard error template](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/view/error/index.phtml) or create your own.

Comment: I don't mean errors like 404 403 etc. I mean errors like I mentioned in question. For example, if I forget to add `module.php` — it cause an error.

Comment: Updated question with an example