# How to remove route on overrided module?

Tags: php, module, routes, zend-framework2

I added `zfcUser` module to my project via Composer and overrided it in the module `ZfcUserOverride`. I want trailing slash work, so I added route in overrided module.

`zfcUserOverride` file `module.config.php` contents below:

```
<?php
$config = array(
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'zfcuser' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'zfcuser' => 'ZfcUserOverride\Controller\UserController',
        ),
    )
);

$config['router']['routes']['zfcuser']['child_routes']['trailing_slash'] = array(
    'type' => 'Literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'zfcuser',
            'action'     => 'index',
        ),
    ),
);

return $config;
```

I added new path, everythin is working correct.

But what if I want remove route? How to do this? I need somethink like:

```
$config['router']['routes']['zfcuser']['child_routes']['login'] = null;
```

Help please. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Here](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/develop/tutorials/config.advanced.html#manipulating-merged-configuration) the answer.

@Sharikov Vladislav, I want to say something to you. 
In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23373374/how-to-override-clone-modules-which-are-downloaded-to-the-vendor-by-composer-in/23375818?noredirect=1#comment35819150_23375818) I answered to your question and you choose the correct answer to somebody that just update his answer with my content 10 hours later.
I do not want to start a flame war, what I ask is just to be correct to whom used its time to help you.

And also I think you must use search engines prior to post here, you are asking a question for every single step of your development process and it is clear you are putting no effort on searching a solution by yourself.

Just sayin..

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't think you are right assuming that I am not researching the problem before I ask. I do this. Another problem is this is new for me and I am not able to extract usefull code from many many many of guides like skeleton apps and others users problems.

Comment: What about reputation? It is not problem I reaccepted question, as you want it. You helped me, yes. But his answer was more helpfull + he had provided much help later. It is not your problem, you don't have to wait, when I will ask something. You wasn't here, he was, he provided more information and helped me much more in sum. Anyway, it is not problem — your answers everywhere are accepted and I hope you satisfied now. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Ok sorry for that, I didn't want to be unpolite with you. Keep up the good work!

Comment: About my problem. This link really helped me. Bookmarked nice site.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav -1 There's no need to be so rude answering a question. Don't judge so fast the capacity of people searching the net looking for answers. The sea of knowledge which is internet could be overwhelming sometimes, specially where you're a newbie on the subject. BTW an answer with a link and 3 words (I don't consider the rest of it constructive or useful for nobody) is not an answer, is a comment.

Comment: @lluisaznar you even mistake the subject... please read carefully the discussion and your own words before judge so fast.

Answer (score 2):

In `zfcUserOverride` you will need to **override** the route config rather than add a new one.

This can easily be done by using the **same** array key when defining the routes.

For example; should I wish to modify the `login` route to allow the extra slash I would use this:

```
// zfcUserOverride/config/module.config.php
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'zfcuser' => array(
            'child_routes' => array(
                'login' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/login[/]',
                    ),
                ),
             ),
         ),
    ),
);
```

Internally ZF2 will combine/merge all module configuration into one complete array using `array_replace_recursive()`. Matching configuration keys will therefore be replaced by modules that have loaded after.

So you will also need to ensure that you have it correctly configured in `application.config.php`

```
array(
    'modules' => array(
        //...
        'ZfcUser',
        'ZfcUserOverride', // Loads after
        // ... 
    ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the question was how to remove this route, not add new. I know how to add new one, as mentioned in my question.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav I have not added a new route; I have modified the existing route that was defined in `ZfcAdmin` to allow for a trailing slash - You do not need to remove it.

Comment: Zfc-user? But I didn't asked how to modify route in this question (I asked about it in another). I asked how to remove route there. Yes, your answer will improve my method, I think I will use it, but it is not answer to the question.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav  Sorry I meant `ZfcUser`; Perhaps I have mis-understood your intent, [overriding the module configuration](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/overriding-module-configuration-in-zf2/) is regarded as the normal method of modifying routes in different modules. If your adamant you want to remove it then you should be able to by accessing the router.

Comment: @AlexP override not overload

Comment: @AlexP As I said. Your answer helped me in another case. How to add trailing slash withour adding child route. I don't need modify route, I need to remove route.