# How to remove route in ZF2?

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I've installed the following modules into my ZF2-Application: [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser), [ZfCAdmin](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcAdmin) and [ZfcUserlist](https://github.com/stijnhau/ZfcUserList). Though my problem is more general, I just want to make clear what I am trying to do.

The `zfcadmin`-route is `/admin`. The `zfcuser`-route is `/user`. The ZfcUserlist-modules is shipped with a child-route for `zfcuser`, is named `zfcuserlist` and points to `/user/list`.

Instead of `/user/list` I want to call the user list by `/admin/user`. That of course is no problem, I just registered a child-route for `zfcadmin`.

Now I want to remove the default route for the user list which is shipped with the module. So my question is: How can I unregister/remove a certain route within ZF2?

To clear things up, I've got the following paths:

```
/admin
/admin/user   <- I added this one
/user/list    <- This comes shipped with the ZfcUserlist-module. I want to remove it
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378766/how-to-remove-route-on-overrided-module

Comment: Have you searched the ZfcUserlist for the string `list`? They probably have a config file where they set list.
If you find that, you can overwrite the name of the route i think.
Another option would be to config the ZfcUserlist module, giving it a route prefix. Such thing probably exists.+

Comment: It's maybe not clear from the answer I linked, but you're looking for this -> http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/develop/tutorials/config.advanced.html#manipulating-merged-configuration

Comment: @AndreschSerj Yes of course I can find the string. I also can override the route, however I want to completly remove it. @Crisp: Your second answer helps. I thought that something like this is possible. I will go this way. But is there a way to do this in a config file - for example by settings the respecting route to `NULL`? This would be easier

Comment: Have you tried looking at the module.config.php under the ZfcUserlist-module/config? All the routes are located there, you can remove it there

Comment: @BryanPosas It is not a good idea to alter third party software i think. Especially not with todays projects using composer and such.

Comment: @BryanPosas Yes I know, however I don't want to alter vendor modules, so that updates will still work in the future.

Comment: @faileN assuming a null value means the key should be removed isn't very reliable when you look at merged config as a whole. The key may be required and the null value may well be valid for some config specs. I think the documented solution was about the best way to deal with it.

Comment: go to the public folder and create a folder named user, try it, you can create manual routes in public folder, and it will override the routes inside of the module, it should find a file or folder named list inside of the user folder, if it's not found, it should throw a 404 error

Comment: @Crisp I implemented it your way. I tested with a `NULL`-value. That however throws an exception. So I think your config-merge-solution is just fine. You may post it as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve what you want you need this in `Module.php`:

```
namespace Foo;

use Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent;
use Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager;

class Module
{
    public function init(ModuleManager $moduleManager)
    {
        $events = $moduleManager->getEventManager();

        // Registering a listener at default priority, 1, which will trigger
        // after the ConfigListener merges config.
        $events->attach(ModuleEvent::EVENT_MERGE_CONFIG, array($this, 'onMergeConfig'));
    }

    public function onMergeConfig(ModuleEvent $e)
    {
        $configListener = $e->getConfigListener();
        $config         = $configListener->getMergedConfig(false);

        // Modify the configuration; here, we'll remove a specific key:
        if (isset($config['router']['routes']['your_route'])) {
            unset($config['router']['routes']['your_route']);
        }

        // Pass the changed configuration back to the listener:
        $configListener->setMergedConfig($config);
    }
}
```

It is just example. You need to change `yout_route` to that part of array, which represents `/user/list`.

### [Source](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/develop/tutorials/config.advanced.html#manipulating-merged-configuration)